# How to add product tags with the same name but different slugs in WooCommerce / WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a WooCommerce website and got a problem with adding tags to our products.

I have two different tags with the **same name** but **different slugs**:

1. tag name: Sugar Free

   - tag slug: sugar-free
2. tag name: Sugar Free

   - tag slug: sugar-free-nuts

I expected WordPress to use slugs to determine equality of two terms but I got a different result.

I added two tags that I explained above to a product, but when I wanted to update the product, one of them removed automatically.

I'm pretty sure WordPress / WooCommerce using the tags name and not slugs to check the equality and doesn't let me add two tags with the same name. I really want to add two tags with the same name but different slugs.

Do you have any idea to resolve this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: You should add a thread to [WooCommerce support pages](https://wordpress.org/support/) relating this problem as this seems a bug like.

Answer (score -1):

change the parent tag of it and then there is a checkbox in right side of the product

Comment: May be you don't know, but product tag terms are not hierarchical, **so there is no parent tag**

Comment: As @LoicTheAztec said, tags are not hierarchical and haven't parent.